# Hive query syntax

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to Hive, please help with the syntax..below are the 2 columns ( filepath, filesize (bytes) ) from the table logstash....

```
/bns/ghi/cod/cob_def/abc                        | 10600
/sandbox/abc/def/xyz/ade                        | 1062659
/data/def/cag/tyz/gj/ibs                        | 457869
/tmp/cdb/def/ghik/new_data/2018-08-17           | 14565
/data/abc/def/ghi/new_data                      | 56453
```

I was able to get the sum filesizes to first level,....

Similarly how do i extract second level eg: ( /data/abc, /bns/ghi, /tmp/cbd )
Eg; If /data is 100 GB I need to know what’s inside /data which is something like /data/def =20 GB /data/efg = 20 GB... and similarly 3rd level

```
**select substr(filepathpath, 2, instr(substr(filepath,2), '/')-2) zone, 
   sum(filesize)from logstash group by substr(filepath, 2, instr(substr(filepath,2), '/')-2)**
```

Answer (score 0):

@user9314128; Please try query below: Hope it helps. Thanks

```
select filepath
,sum(filesize) as sumfilesize
from logstash 
where length(regexp_replace(filepath,'[^/]','')) = 1
group by filepath;
```

For 2nd level; change the where clause from = 1 to = 2

Comment: Executing the above query i get all the first level required but filesize is 0.             Filepath                                          Filesize                                                                                                                                           
 /app            |                                       0
/data            |                                       0
/tmp             |                                       0

Comment: I am not able to get total filesize value...everything returned is 0

Comment: @user9314128; also double check the value of filesize if all are in fact zero or null.

Comment: I have approx 30 million files and few files may be 0 bytes but rest are not....i am trying sum up all filesizes to first level based on there directory structure....

Comment: @user9314128; let us check the data value of column filesize. Kindly give us the result of this query:  select min(filesize) as minfilesize
,max(filesize) as maxfilesize
from logstash 
where length(regexp_replace(filepath,'[^/]','')) = 1;

Comment: I get 0 for both min & max filesize..with above query

Comment: @user9314128; then sum(filesize) is indeed zero. :)  It means there is no files on level1 and the query I put in the answer is correct

Comment: Thanks…there were some data issue which is fixed...I was able to get the sum of filesize to first level.../data ,/tmp ,/bns, /sandbox...how do I sum the filesize at second level with each individual directories....eg: /data is 100 GB I need to know what’s inside /data which is something like /data/def =20 GB /data/efg = 20 GB... and similarly 3rd level...I changed the following query to 2 but didn't help select substr(filepath, 2, instr(substr(filepath,2), '/')-2) zone, filesize from logstashgroup by substr(filepath, 2, instr(substr(filepath,2), '/')-2);

Comment: @user9314128; 2nd level folder means that there there two '/' in the filepath so this command: length(regexp_replace(filepath,'[^/]','')) = 2 will sum up all folders for 2nd level

Answer (score 0):

Use Split and CONCAT_WS

1 Level

```
select split(filepath, '/')[0] as 1_level_path,filesize from logstash;
```

1 Level with filesize sum.

```
select split(filepath, '/')[0] as 1_level_path,SUM(filesize) 
from logstash
group by split(filepath, '/')[0] ;
```

2 Levels

```
select CONCAT_WS('/',split(filepath, '/')[0],split(filepath, '/')[1]),filesize from logstash;
```

3 Levels

```
 select CONCAT_WS('/',CONCAT_WS('/',split(filepath, '/')[0],split(filepath, '/')[1]),split(filepath, '/')[2])),filesize from logstash
```

Comment: using the first query i don't get only the first level, I get duplicate value. /data is repeated in more than one row. I need a total value ( total filesize ) for /data, /tmp, /bns and so on...

Comment: @user9314128 Your question does not say that you are looking to sum the filesize for 1st level of path and so on.

Comment: @user9314128 I've added the sum part. You just need to group by the 1st level